# google charts, change trendline equation parameter labels

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, jsapi, pygooglechart

I want to change the equation parameters label (only) from `Age` and `Diameter` to `Y` and `X` 
from `(Age = 4.885 * Diameter + 0.73)` to `(Y = 4.885 * X + 0.73)`
in the title and inside the tooltip.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Diameter', 'Age'],
    [8, 37], [4, 19.5], [11, 52], [4, 22], [3, 16.5], [6.5, 32.8], [14, 72]]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Age of sugar maples vs. trunk diameter, in inches',
    hAxis: {title: 'Diameter'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Age'},
    legend: {
      alignment: 'end',
      position: 'top'
    },
    series: {
      0: {
        visibleInLegend: true
      }
    },
    trendlines: {
      0: {
        visibleInLegend: true
      }
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var equation = $('text[text-anchor="start"][fill="#222222"]').text();
    console.log(equation);
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

can some one help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are no standard options,
you would need to change manually on the chart's `'ready'` event.

but it might be easier to change the column labels to `'X', 'Y'`,
then manually change the title of the series to `'Age'`...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['X', 'Y'],
    [8, 37], [4, 19.5], [11, 52], [4, 22], [3, 16.5], [6.5, 32.8], [14, 72]]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Age of sugar maples vs. trunk diameter, in inches',
    hAxis: {title: 'Diameter'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Age'},
    legend: {
      alignment: 'end',
      position: 'top'
    },
    series: {
      0: {
        visibleInLegend: true
      }
    },
    trendlines: {
      0: {
        visibleInLegend: true
      }
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var equation = $('text[text-anchor="start"][fill="#222222"]').get(0);
    equation.textContent = 'Age';
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**EDIT**

to display `'Age'` as the series title in the tooltip,
you can use a custom tooltip.

here, a data view is used to add the tooltip column.

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, {
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    return 'Age\n' + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0) + ', ' + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1);
  },
  role: 'tooltip',
  type: 'string'
}]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['X', 'Y'],
    [8, 37], [4, 19.5], [11, 52], [4, 22], [3, 16.5], [6.5, 32.8], [14, 72]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return 'Age\n' + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0) + ', ' + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1);
    },
    role: 'tooltip',
    type: 'string'
  }]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Age of sugar maples vs. trunk diameter, in inches',
    hAxis: {title: 'Diameter'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Age'},
    legend: {
      alignment: 'end',
      position: 'top'
    },
    series: {
      0: {
        visibleInLegend: true
      }
    },
    trendlines: {
      0: {
        visibleInLegend: true
      }
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var equation = $('text[text-anchor="start"][fill="#222222"]').get(0);
    equation.textContent = 'Age';
  });

  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help, but I still need to show the "Age" in the hover over the dot points, and I still can't figure out how.

Comment: is there any way to show numbers in European format? @WhiteHat

Comment: have you tried adjusting the [locale](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#loadwithlocale)?